# Base extension of the Weil restriction

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

It is a problem in Waterhouse's book, "Affine group schemes, p 61":

1. (a) Let $B$ be finite dimensional (commutative) $k$-algebra. Let $G$ be an affine group scheme over $B$. Define the Weil restriction $F$ of $G$ to $k$ by $F(R) = G(R\otimes_k B)$. ...

> (b)If $B/k$ is a Galois field extension, show $F_B \simeq G\times \ldots \times G.$

My answer for the part (b) is:

$$F_B \simeq \prod_{\sigma \in \mathrm{Gal}(B/k)} G\times_\sigma Spec(B).$$

Is this group equivalent to $G\times\ldots\times G$? If not, does there exist a simple example which shows these aren't equivalent?

Comment: It is false (using $k$-isomorphisms)! For example, suppose $G = {\rm{SO}}(q)$ for a non-degenerate quadratic space $(V,q)$ over $B$ of dimension $\ge 3$, with $[B:k] > 1$.  Then $F_B = \prod_{\sigma} {\rm{SO}}(q_{\sigma})$ as a direct product of absolutely simple semisimple groups (with $q_{\sigma}$ the $\sigma$-twist of $q$), so by uniqueness of such decomposition this cannot be isomorphic to a power of $G$ unless ${\rm{SO}}(q_{\sigma}) \simeq {\rm{SO}}(q)$ for all $\sigma$. But that happens iff $q_{\sigma}$ and $q$ are homothetic for all $\sigma$, which is generally false.

Comment: @user52824 Thank's, you have answered all of my questions above. But can you give me a reference for the uniqueness of this kind of decompositions?

Comment: I thought that the product decomposition comes from the fact that in the situation of (b), we have $B\otimes_kB\cong \prod_{\operatorname{Gal}(B/k)} B$. This should induce the product decomposition of groups because it is a functorial product decomposition of $R$-points of $F_B$ for all $B$-algebras $R$.

Comment: @MatthiasWendt: The isomorphism you mention transports the two natural (but distinct, when $[B:k]>1$) $B$-algebra structures on the left side over to the "diagonal" and "Galois" structures on the right side, and one has to keep careful track of that to see that Waterhouse's formulation is simply wrong.

Comment: @Mostafa: Let $\{G_i\}$ be any finite collection of $k$-simple connected semisimple groups over a field $k$, and let $G = \prod G_i$.  For any $k$-simple connected semisimple normal $k$-subgroup $N \subset G$, $(N,G_i)$ must be nontrivial for some $i$ (otherwise $N$ would be central and hence finite, a contradiction), yet that nontrivial commutator is normal in both $G_i$ and $N$, whence coincides with each as a $k$-subgroup of $G$ by $k$-simplicity of each.

Comment: @user52824: Interesting, and good to know. Thanks for the instructive example.